# change multiple panel on button click wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I would like to write simple code with 2 panels. multiple button on left side panel and respective page on right side panel which will display when button is clicked. Each Button clicked changes panel to respective page with necessary input fields for further processing. I do not know how can I achieve that. 
Below is sample UI for reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6SGA.jpg

I came across below code which logic fulfill my requirement to some extent but it opens new panel

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
""""""


def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
""""""

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
    grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)


 class MyForm(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                      "Panel Switcher Tutorial")

    self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
    self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
    self.panel_two.Hide()

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 
                                              "Switch Panels", 
                                              "Some text")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels, 
              switch_panels_menu_item)
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)


  def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
    """"""
    if self.panel_one.IsShown():
        self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
        self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.panel_two.Show()
    else:
        self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
        self.panel_one.Show()
        self.panel_two.Hide()
    self.Layout()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.App(False)
  frame =MyForm()
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend checking out the `wx.Listbook` control. There is a good example in the wxPython demo or you could also check out this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/)

There is also a tutorial on the [wxPython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Listbook)